# How get data where they similar to a tuple?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I want to select data from a table that similar to a tuple. It mean I get just data that like in my tuple for example t1

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
result = cur.execute("SELECT Sum(amount) FROM items WHERE id In 't1' ")
c1 = cur.fetchall()
```

But I get this error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: t1

Comment: What is t1?....

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a column from the table.

`SELECT Sum(amount) From items Where Id In (Select Col1 from TableName)`

If you want to get values that match multiple columns, then the inner select should union those columns.

`SELECT Sum(amount) From items Where Id In (Select Col1 from TableName Union Select Col2 from TableName)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But the problem is we don't know how many items in the tuple (t1). I want get data from column amount just match with the tuple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to create a query with enough bind replace  variables which are equal to the number of elements in the tuple.
For that we need to replicate binds `?`.

Refer below code and [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-write-an-SQL-IN-query-with-a-Python-tuple).

```
import sqlite3
var_tuple=(1,2,3)
#  Connect
con = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\path\testdb.db")
replace_var= '?'
replace_var= ', '.join(replace_var for _ in var_tuple)
query= 'select * from table_1 where c2 in (%s)' % replace_var
print (query)
#  cursor
cur = con.cursor()
for row in cur.execute(query,var_tuple):
    print(row)
con.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But the problem is we don't know how many items in the tuple (t1). I want get data from column amount just match with the tuple. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes got that. The code I shared, addresses that only where we dont know how many items in tuple. Otherwise, we can just hard-code ```?``` times the number of tuple. To avoid same we are dynamically building a query that includes bind variable(s). The ```for loop``` in the program takes care of automatically getting number of elements present in tuple.